# How to post real time errors in web to lead form?

Tags: web2lead

I want to show an error message if a lead has a duplicate field record. The message should be on the form itself. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web-to-Lead is an asynchronous service. You can use JavaScript to validate the input, but you cannot use validation rules or triggers to display errors using Web-to-Lead. If you need this type of functionality, you';; want to set up a Site or write your own API integration to capture leads.